# Alternative to WebGL if not loading

Tags: php, javascript, html, webgl, alt

I have some WebGL stuff in an iframe. On some web browsers or old computers, the iframe isn't loading. When this happens I'd like to load an image instead. Is it possible and if yes how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be good if you could [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12585898/edit) and add some code what you have already tried. This way you will get better and more precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

Wether or not WebGL is supported is probably best checked the same way you do in Javascript

```
WebGLRenderingContext gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl")

if(!gl)
{
    $("#image").show()
}
```

Comment: You are welcome , if it answers your question .. you can click on accept by the side

Comment: hi and thx for ur answer but i can't get it working.
My code is : 
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">';
     echo'WebGLRenderingContext gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl")';
     echo'if(!gl){';
  echo'var Nom = new Image();';
  echo'var Nom.src = "iphone5.jpg";';
      echo'$("Nom").show()}';
      echo'else{';
      echo'<center><iframe ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" frameborder="0" height="340" width="454" src="http://skfb.ly/k4i3g2fe1?autostart=1&transparent=0&autospin=0&controls=1&watermark=1"></iframe></center>}</script>';

but there is neither the webgl animation nor the image

Comment: Please you need to have predefined the image , i was just showing how to check for webGL

Answer (score 1):

### Problems in `<script>`:

First of all it seems that you have some problems within your `<script>` tag. There is plain `<center><iframe ...` HTML tags inside `<script>` tag which does not work as there should be only javascript here. There is also some missing `;` semicolons.

### Solutions to detect WebGL:

You could try this one but I also recommend checking out linked sites at end of my answer:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = "http://domain.tld/picture.jpg";
    $(myImage).prependTo(document.body);
} else {
    $(document.body).prepend('<center><iframe ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" frameborder="0" height="340" width="454" src="CORRECT THIS FIELD"></iframe></center>');
}
</script>
<?php
```

Just add `echos` for PHP and correct `<iframe src="CORRECT THIS FIELD">` attribute, also set image url to something that really exists.

In place of `document.body` you could use for example `'#myWebGLArea'` and add `<div id="myWebGLArea"></div>` to your page.

### More on topic:

Also check out WebGL detection script at https://gist.github.com/1709384 and another Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904965/1338846